# Why do I need to install SSMS to open Crystal Reports from remote PC

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a Visual Basic .NET application located on a server in the network. When I run the application from a PC in the network it works fine. The login/password is checked and all information is loaded from the database. The only thing that is not working is opening a Crystal Report. I get the following popup:

[image]

When I install SSMS version 18.12.1 on the PC the problem is solved. I don't even have to open SSMS once. The question is: what part of SSMS makes it work? I tried to install only Microsoft® ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server® but that didn't solve it.

Comment: Installed Microsoft OLE DB Driver 19 for SQL Server (x64) which didn't do the trick either

Comment: Installed Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Native Client and it looks like this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Installed Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Native Client was the solution for my problem